# Elasticsearch auto-complete not working correctly

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 2 product name called "satiny" when i try to type sat it doesn't appear.
[image]

But when i type "sati" then "satiny" appears first then some other product and then my second "satiny" product.
[image]

I have implemented Fuzzy search, Edge-ngram, Synonym search.

This is my Index :

```
{"settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "synonym" : {
                    "type": "synonym",
                    "synonyms_path": "analysis/synonym.txt"                            
                        }

        },
        "analyzer": 
            {
              "synonym" : {
                    "tokenizer" : "whitespace",
                    "filter" : ["lowercase",
                    "synonym"]
                },

          "keyword_analyzer": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "asciifolding",
              "trim"
            ],
            "char_filter": [],
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "keyword"
          },
          "edge_ngram_analyzer": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercase"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "edge_ngram_tokenizer"
          },
          "edge_ngram_search_analyzer": {
            "tokenizer": "lowercase"
          }
            },  

        "tokenizer": {
          "edge_ngram_tokenizer": {
            "type": "edge_ngram",
            "min_gram": 1,
            "max_gram": 25,
            "token_chars": [
              "letter"
            ]
          }

  },
    "mappings": {
            "properties" : {
            "firebaseId":{
            "type":"text"
            },
                "name" : {
                   "type" : "text",
                   "analyzer" : "synonym"

                },
                "name_auto" : {
                "type": "text",

    "fields": {
      "edgengram": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "edge_ngram_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "edge_ngram_search_analyzer"
      },
      "completion": {
        "type": "completion"
      }

    }
                },

                "category_name" : {
                            "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                  "keyword": { 
                                    "type": "keyword"
                            }
                }
                },
                "storeName" : {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "sku" : {
                    "type" : "text"
                },
                "price" : {
                    "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": { 
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                }
                },
                "magento_id" : {
                    "type" : "text"
                },
                "seller_id" : {
                    "type" : "text"
                },
                "square_item_id" : {
                    "type" : "text"
                },
                "square_variation_id" : {
                    "type" : "text"
                },
                "typeId" : {
                    "type" : "text"
                }
            }
    }
}
}
}
}
```

And This is my query :

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 50,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "bool": {
                    "should": [{
                        "match_phrase": {
                            "name_auto.edgengram": "sati"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "match_phrase": {
                            "name_auto": "sati"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "match": {
                            "name_auto": "sati"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "match": {
                            "category_name": {
                                "query": "sati",
                                "analyzer": "synonym"
                            }
                        }
                    }, {
                        "match_phrase": {
                            "category_name": "sati"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "match": {
                            "name": {
                                "query": "sati",
                                "fuzziness": 2,
                                "prefix_length": 1
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

when i type "sat" then the edge-ngram should start and show me the product named "satiny"  first and then the fuzzy search implementation should start and show me the products with "sol" or "set" as such

I got it partially solved but still  i want all the product names with "charcoal" to appear first .

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that your `mappings` section is not located properly at the top-level next to `settings`. It is located inside `settings.index.analysis` instead, hence none of your fields is properly defined. It would help to properly format your JSON.

Create your index like this and it should work:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "synonym": {
            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase"
            ]
          },
          "keyword_analyzer": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "asciifolding",
              "trim"
            ],
            "char_filter": [],
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "keyword"
          },
          "edge_ngram_analyzer": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercase"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "edge_ngram_tokenizer"
          },
          "edge_ngram_search_analyzer": {
            "tokenizer": "lowercase"
          }
        },
        "tokenizer": {
          "edge_ngram_tokenizer": {
            "type": "edge_ngram",
            "min_gram": 1,
            "max_gram": 25,
            "token_chars": [
              "letter"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "firebaseId": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "synonym"
      },
      "name_auto": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "edgengram": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "edge_ngram_analyzer",
            "search_analyzer": "edge_ngram_search_analyzer"
          },
          "completion": {
            "type": "completion"
          }
        }
      },
      "category_name": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "storeName": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "sku": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "price": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "magento_id": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "seller_id": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "square_item_id": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "square_variation_id": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "typeId": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hey Val , tanks for your reponse,if this is the solution ,is there a way to update/replace the existing index with the current one ?because my data comes via trigger.

Comment: In my opinion, it's going to be difficult because all your fields were created with default settings in your index mapping (you can check with `GET your-index`)  and you won't be allowed to modify the existing field definitions. You can still create the new index with the proper mapping and then use the [Reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) to move the data from your old index to the new one.

Comment: Thanks again val i can copy my data from old index to new one . This time i have a product name "Catalina" when i send a request by providing "ca" then the first product that should appear is "Catalina" but instead i am getting "Olive Night Cap" and "Carrall Peach Bloom Cardi" the products starting with "ca" should appear first but its not.

Comment: Since the issue here was more about your mapping, let's close this question and create a new one, so we don't cram too many things into a single thread.

Comment: Hey Val created a new thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57521842/elasticsearch-auto-complete-not-working-as-desired

Comment: Hey Val this issue is partially solved , i have added a screenshot at the end of the question please have a look at it .

Comment: ok its done ,but i still believe the auto-complete doesn't work as expected

Comment: It sure doesn't but the first issue (wrong mapping location) is solved, now onto the next.